# Compare two Spark Schemas in Java, Unable to Cast Seq<StructField> to List<StructField>

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

Problem : I want to get common attributes between two schemas in DDL Format.

I have following working code to get intersection of schemas in scala :

```
val diff = df1.schema.intersect(df2.schema)
val sb = new StringBuilder(); 
diff.toStream.foreach(x => sb.append( x.toDDL + ", "))
```

But I am facing conversion issues when converting this piece to Java :

```
StructType s1 = new StructType().add("col1",StringType)
                                .add("col2",StringType)
                                .add("col3",StringType)
                                .add("col4",StringType);

StructType s2 = new StructType().add("col1",StringType)
                                .add("col4",StringType);

System.out.println("Output :" + s1.toList().intersect(s2.toList()));
```

```
Output :List(StructField(col1,StringType,true), StructField(col4,StringType,true))
```

I am unable to convert this Output to DDL. I tried reading above object as Seq but it fails with compilation error :

```
    Seq<StructField> result = s1.toList().intersect(s2.toList());

Error: java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to scala.collection.Seq<org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField>
```

Another try :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    s1.toList().intersect(s2.toList()).foreach( (schema) -> sb.append(schema.toDDL() + ","));

Error:(81, 39) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method foreach((schema)->[...] ","))
  location: class java.lang.Object
```

Any pointers on how to read this as a `List<StructType>`, so that I can convert it to DDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know is to use `JavaConversions`, something like

```
Object something = s1.toList().intersect(s2.toList());
List<StructField> result = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList((Seq<StructField>)something);
System.out.println("Output :" + result);
```

...which will print

```
Output :[StructField(col1,StringType,true), StructField(col4,StringType,true)]
```